# Objectify - loading child entity in separate thread produces inconsistent results

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

fetch a list of objects . Use multi threading to fetch children objects and do some processing. collect all results and send to UI. threads produce inconsistent results. Some of the threads throw an error while some work fine.
sample code : 
entities : Parent, Child

```
Parent {
    Ref<Child> childKey ;
    public Child getChild(){
        return childKey.get();
    }
}

    List<Parent> parents ; //get from db
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20, ThreadManager.currentRequestThreadFactory());
            List<Future<ParentTO>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Parent parent : parents) {
                Future<ParentTO> future = executorService.submit(() -> {
                return  ObjectifyService.run(new Work<ParentTO>() {
                        public ParentTO run() {
                            parent.getChild();                      ParentTO to = new ParentTO();

                            return to;
                        }
                    });
                });

            }
```

Error only shows on appengine and for some threads. It works fine on local server. If i reload page i see different results every time. Without threads it works fine.

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.googlecode.objectify.LoadException: Error loading Parent("FND1clkiTUa_lWsJow-Dxwdmadma")/Child(1): null
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:206)
    at com.netkiller.erp.service.ParentService.ParentsToApprovalTOs(ParentService.java:1720)
    at com.netkiller.erp.service.ParentService.getSharedParentsUI(ParentService.java:2000)
    at com.netkiller.common.controller.ParentController.fetchSharedParents(ParentController.java:1266)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:214)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:690)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1772)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
    at com.netkiller.common.filter.OpenIdFilter.doFilter(OpenIdFilter.java:859)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
    at com.netkiller.common.filter.ServiceFilter.doFilter(ServiceFilter.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
    at com.netkiller.common.filter.SecureProtocolFilter.doFilter(SecureProtocolFilter.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter.doFilter(ObjectifyFilter.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.ParseBlobUploadHandler.handle(ParseBlobUploadHandler.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1182)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppEngineWebAppContext.doHandle(AppEngineWebAppContext.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:293)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:539)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:333)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.RpcConnection.handle(RpcConnection.java:213)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.RpcConnector.serviceRequest(RpcConnector.java:81)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:123)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchServletRequest(JavaRuntime.java:692)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchRequest(JavaRuntime.java:655)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:625)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$NullSandboxRequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:817)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:269)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.googlecode.objectify.LoadException: Error loading Parent("FND1clkiTUa_lWsJow-Dxwdmadma")/Child(1): null
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.EntityMetadata.load(EntityMetadata.java:78)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.LoadEngine.load(LoadEngine.java:185)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.LoadEngine$1.nowUncached(LoadEngine.java:141)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.LoadEngine$1.nowUncached(LoadEngine.java:127)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultCache.now(ResultCache.java:30)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Round$1.nowUncached(Round.java:71)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultCache.now(ResultCache.java:30)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.LoaderImpl.now(LoaderImpl.java:251)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.ref.LiveRef.get(LiveRef.java:47)
    at com.netkiller.erp.domain.Parent.getChild(Parent.java:187)
    at com.netkiller.common.dto.ApprovalTO.<init>(ApprovalTO.java:503)
    at com.netkiller.erp.service.ParentService$2.run(ParentService.java:1708)
    at com.netkiller.erp.service.ParentService$2.run(ParentService.java:1)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService.run(ObjectifyService.java:81)
    at com.netkiller.erp.service.ParentService.lambda$8(ParentService.java:1706)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$CurrentRequestThreadFactory.lambda$newThread$0(ApiProxyImpl.java:1213)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$CurrentRequestThreadFactory.lambda$newThread$1(ApiProxyImpl.java:1209)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$CurrentRequestThread.run(ApiProxyImpl.java:1185)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.ArrayDeque.removeLast(ArrayDeque.java:295)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.LoadContext.exitContainerContext(LoadContext.java:141)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassPopulator.load(ClassPopulator.java:119)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslator.loadSafe(ClassTranslator.java:122)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslator.loadSafe(ClassTranslator.java:21)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.NullSafeTranslator.load(NullSafeTranslator.java:17)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.EntityMetadata.load(EntityMetadata.java:74)
    ... 22 more
```

Thanks for any insight on the issue.

Comment: What version of Objectify are you using?

Comment: Objectify version : 5.1.22

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell exactly what's going on from the provided code, but it's easy to accidentally contaminate data when operating across multiple threads.

To reduce the chance that you're accidentally pulling data from the wrong thread's session, use `ofy().load()` to load everything instead of following refs. You can pass a `Ref` to `ofy().load().ref(theRef)`.

If you always call `ofy()` then you will always get an instance correct for your thread of execution. Try that out and if you still have an issue, we can continue this discussion with whatever error message you see.

Comment: Yes, using ofy().load() in child threads works fine. Using reference generates this error. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @stickfigure, 
I forked objectify code to find this error. I am able to fix this error by following change -
LiveRef has a constructor that takes and stores Objectify ofy . 
I changed to always use a new instance of ofy() rather then the one saved and it fixes this issue. 
with maven lib 5.1.22 you will see different number of result (not considering order) every time you reload
https://10-dot-motaboga.appspot.com/hello/fetch
With modifed git lib (branch v5) everytime you see same number of result
https://12-dot-motaboga.appspot.com/hello/fetch

Comment: ran out of characters. Can you suggest what to do with these findings ?